# Crash in tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 18 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b11b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c6140e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b07695 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
    3   MyPocket                            0x0005efe9 -[loginLocalitems tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 638
    4   UIKit                               0x00be9a48 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
    5   UIKit                               0x00be032e -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 219
    6   Foundation                          0x0037821a __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x02af2f73 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x02af45b4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1364
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x02a50dd9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x02a50350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x02a50271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x03f4e00c GSEventRunModal + 217
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x03f4e0d1 GSEventRun + 115
    14  UIKit                               0x00b84af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    15  MyPocket                            0x000023d2 main + 84
    16  MyPocket                            0x00002375 start + 53
    17  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

What is the reason for the above array. This crash appears only when i select the lower cells of table view Anyone pls help

Comment: Post your code from  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that your NSMutableArray has only from 0 to 16 objects inside. When you scroll to the bottom of the table and select the lower cell you are trying to access an object in the array at index higher then 16. So try to check if the array that you are using for the table is properly filled, and that you are not removing something from it at later time.

Answer (score 3):

you are loading data from a mutable array?
check if the array really has 18 elements.
or if you are giving a number bigger than the actual row count in the numberOfRows inSection method

this is a range exception:

```
index 18 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]
```

as you see, it only occurs when you click the lower items